# Proving a statement about a function with exactly two extrema

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ with exactly two
>   extrema points $a$ and $b$. Suppose $a<b$ and $f(a)<f(b)$. Prove that
>   $f(a)$ is a local minimum.

Proof: Suppose $f(a)$ is not a local minimum. $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, so by the extreme value theorem it attains a minimum and a maximum there. It can't attain the min/max in $(a,b)$ because then it will mean that there is an additional local extrema which contradicts the fact that $f$ has exactly two extrema. So $f$ attains maximum and minimum in the end points. Because $f(a)<f(b)$, $f(a)$ is the minimum. Because we assumed that $f(a)$ is a local maximum, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\leq f(a)$ for all $x\in(a,a+\delta)$. On the other hand, $f(a)$ is the minimum in $[a,b]$ and thus $f(a)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,a+\delta)$. Then $f(a)=f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,a+\delta)$, but then, any $x\in(a,a+\delta)$ is a minimum too and thus an extremum, which is a contradiction.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Is it possible that $x$ isn't a minimum for the entire function?

Comment: Yes this is correct, however you could expand this: you could prove that for any function of one variable, if there are two extrema than there must be a local minimum and a local maximum.

Comment: @Jan - thank you. Unfortunately, I didn't have time to expand in my exam :(